# Linq Regex for whole word search

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'm unable to find a recent decent answer on this.

Linq does not support regex, and trying to extract a method out does not outsmart the framwork. How do I do a whole work match on a list of sentences in linq.

The reason I need the \b is because it could be start or end of string, or have a comma, dash, or other similar separators.

```
    private bool isMatch(string searchText, string text)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(searchText, "\\b"+text+"\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }


        result  p = itemsRep
            .Where(fullText=> isMatch(searchText, fullText))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Find the first match? If so you don't need linq. Find the first word that matches? you are not using "s" in the lamda at all.

Comment: Linq supports anything you can write in .NET. Linq-to-Entities, Linq-to-SQL, etc. may not. What Linq provider are you using?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: for "ski" "I like to ski" "i like to ski, but no", "ski- i like it" should match but not "i like skiing" "skies are blue"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're saying is that Linq-to-SQL/Linq-To-Entities does not support `Regex` in expressions.

Try adding `.AsEnumerable()` before your `.Where()`.

The `.Where()` method will then enumerate over the results of any translated query, rather than try to convert your `.Where()` expression to SQL.

Like this:

```
result  p = itemsRep
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(fullText => isMatch(searchText, fullText))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: They can support regex, but only if you create a SQLCLR scalar function and consume that function in your LINQ query. You're correct that you can't use Regex out of the box otherwise.