# Whole word search in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can I search for whole word in LINQ?

If I am searching for a word "car"  in a list of strings `{"carpenter","car repair","carrying","car workshop"}` etc. And the result should be "car repair" & "car workshop" only .
I tries the below code

```
  List<string> _tags = (from item in string_array
                                 where item.ToLower().Contains(search_term)
                                 select item).ToList();
```

But, contains always return similar words and I found this link on SO [Linq Regex for whole word search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711822/linq-regex-for-whole-word-search)
which is not providing a complete answer using Regx.

So, anyone can help to write an answer in Regx or is any other options to use with Linq.

Comment: @SonerGönül, what to do with `car,` ?

Comment: @AlexSikilinda Fail, of course.

Comment: adding `item.ToLower().Split(' ').Length > 1` to the `where` clause yields what you want, but obviously it's not a solution.

Comment: I'm afraid LINQ has very little to do with the problem. The main problem is whole word search and has been solved in SO already.

Comment: How you deal with `'s`, for example, if you have such input `Alex's pen`, and you search for `Alex`, should it be in the result list?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = items.Where(i => i.Split(' ').Any(word => word.ToLower() == "car")).ToList();
```

If you need to take into account commas, you can use this instead:

```
var reg = new Regex("\\bcar\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var items = new [] { "carpenter", "car repair", "carrying", "car workshop", "car, repair", "car. repair", "car,repair" };
var result = items.Where(word => reg.IsMatch(word)).ToList();
```

Gives:

```
car repair 
car workshop 
car, repair 
car. repair 
car,repair
```

Comment: you did the same thing as I did, but there might be more exact way to achieve the same. :)

Comment: @Rob how can i apply the same for a list of object with specific property ?Example a List<Image> and i want to apply the Regx for Name &  Title properties

Comment: If `Image` has a property `Name` and `images` was `List<Image>`, then you could write: `images.Where(image => reg.IsMatch(image.Name)).ToList()`

Comment: The approach with a word-bounded Regex is exactly the one I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.Where(item=>item.Split(' ').Contains("car"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

- Split each item in the array on white space using `string.Split()`
- Search for the word using `Contains` using `StringComaparer` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.95).aspx)

like:

```
string[] string_array = {"carpenter", "car repair", "carrying", "car workshop"};
string word = "car";
 List<string> _tags = string_array.Where(r => r.Split()
                               .Contains(word, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                  .ToList();
```

For output:

```
foreach (var item in _tags)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output would be:

```
car repair
car workshop
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just look for a spaces before and after search keyword.

```
   List<string> _tags = string_array.Where(
       s => s.ToUpper().Contains(" " + search_term.ToUpper()) ||   
         sToUpper().Contains(search_term.ToUpper() + " ") || s.ToUpper == search_term.ToUpper()).ToList();
```

Comment: We cant don it , Since it will not consider sentences starting with word example : car mechanic and if we add space before and after car " car " same is the case of sentence ends with word

Comment: Here we select all string that has at least one of :  (i'll replace spaces with underscores for clarity)  :  'car'    'car_'    '_car'.  For a list of values {"car mechanic", "car", "carbon", "black car"}  it'll match 3 of them - all except 'carbon'.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var strResult = strings.Where(x => x.Split(' ').Any(y => y.Equals("car"))).ToList();
```

Comment: Can we do it??? , Since it will not consider sentences starting with word example : car mechanic and if we add space before and after car " car " same is the case of sentence ends with word –